# Using NodeJS with PostgreSQL don't insert last data from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using NodeJS 8.9.3 with Node-Postgres to process some data from a source before insert it on a database. The data was processed and put into an hash. However, the last item from this hash isn't inserted for some reason, even the item being parsed by the forEach() block. All the other items are correctly added.

My code until now:

```html
filtradas.forEach((key) =>
                  {
                      var valor=processa[key];
                      console.log(key, valor);
                      var campos=key.split('_');

                      (async () =>
                       {
                           const client=await connection.connect();
                           try
                           {
                               const res=await client.query("INSERT INTO dados VALUES (CAST($1 AS TIMESTAMP),$2,$3,$4)",
                                                            [parseData, campos[1], campos[0], valor]);
                           }
                           finally
                           {
                               client.release();
                           }
                       })().catch(e =>
                                  {
                                      console.log(e.stack);
                                      process.exit(-1);
                                  });
                  });
```

`filtradas` is an Array of strings containing the hash keys I want to process there (there's some I filtered before for other uses), while `processa` is all the data. The hash is basically data on the ormat

```
{ 
  FOO: 2,
  BAR: 3,
  BAZ: 4
}
```

but BAZ isn't recorded on my PostgreSQL database, only FOO and BAR.

The `console.log(key, valor)`, however, shows BAR...

Anything I'm doing wrong? Using the asynchrous mode is a bad idea on the case?

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from my friends I came with a solution on the code below.

```html
filtradas.map((key) =>
                 {
                     var valor=processa[key];
                     var campos=key.split('_');

                     (async() =>
                      {
                          const client=await connection.connect().catch(e => { console.error(e.stack) } );
                          const res=await client.query("INSERT INTO dados VALUES (CAST($1 AS TIMESTAMP),$2,$3,$4)", [parseData, campos[1], campos[0], valor]).catch(e => { console.error(e.stack) } );
                          await client.release();
                      })().catch(e =>
                                 {
                                     console.log(e.stack);
                                     process.exit(-1);
                                 });
                   
                  });

connection.end();
```

According them, my original code was not working correctly their promises, so the last entry wasn't working